# Kotlin list modifies by itself

Tags: android, list, kotlin, arraylist

Why list is modified??

```
val list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
list.add("a")
list.add("b")
list.add("c")
println(list)
val newL = list
val a = newL.find{it=="c"}
newL.remove(a)
newL.add("z")
println(list)
println(newL)
```

and the out put is

> [a, b, c]

> [a, b, z]

> [a, b, z]

Comment: In log the change is that the quantity adds to product with same name

Comment: `list` and `newL` both refer to the same `ArrayList` instance.